# An application of Holder's Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, holder-inequality

Suppose $1\leq p,q\leq \infty$ and $1/p+1/q=1$. Let $f\in\mathcal{L}^p(E)$. Show that $f=0$ a.e. if and only if 
\begin{align*}
    \int_E f\cdot gdm=0
\end{align*}
for all $g\in \mathcal{L}^q(E)$. Hint: Choose a smart $g$ so that $\int_Ef\cdot gdm=\|f\|_p^p$.

Comment: In fact, if $f \in L^p(E)$ then $$\|f\|_p = \sup_{g \in L^q(E)} \int_E fg \, dm.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try $g=\mathrm{sign}(f)\cdot|f|^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.

> Second hint: $\alpha=p/q$.